# please explain how to force line breaks in the help for blockquotes

Tags: support

I wasted a lot of time in trial and error before I discovered that

> you need to end each line
>   in a blockquote with
>   two spaces
>   in order to force linebreaks

**Please add this to the help for blockquotes**

Comment: You can use the html tag `<br>`

Answer (score 4):

#### Please add this to the help for blockquotes

Note: The 2 space markdown for `<br/>` is not specific to blockquotes, but is also valid markdown for regular text.

It is, however, already in the [Markdown help](https://meta.superuser.com/editing-help), which is accessed by clicking the [advanced help](https://meta.superuser.com/editing-help) link when using the question or answer markdown editor.

1. Click the "Markdown Editing Help" icon

[image]

2. Click advanced help.

[image]

[image]

Comment: … and it's not in the help for blockquotes as this is not specific to those, it applies to regular text as well.

Comment: @DanielBeck Good point. Answer updated.